# JQuery IE <div> opacity problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a problem with IE.
I have a layer that has this style to make it transparent and fullscreen.

```
position:absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
background-color: #000000;
filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
-moz-opacity: 0.5; 
opacity: 0.5;
z-index: 1;
```

And i use the JQuery method fadeIn and fadeOut to show and hide it.
Well all well in Opera locks great but IE7 Just overides the style and sets it to 100% opacity. it dosent even fade!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Peter-Paul Koch has a [fantastic article on opacity](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html).  In general, quirksmode.org is the first place I go to solve browser-compatibility issues; PPK's done a great deal of research. That said, you look like you have all the right styles in place - is jquery's fadein implementation not doing the right thing, even when you give it a target opacity?

Could you solve the problem by setting the declared CSS to fully-opaque but visible:false, and then use [fadeto](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeTo) to get to the target opacity?

Comment: I'd go with this solution. IE's support for opacity is abysmal, so you'd be better off initializing the div with visibility: hidden; or display: none; and then making it visible and fade when it's activated. This way, the fade effect will work where it's supported, and fall back on simply displaying the div where it isn't.

Comment: How do i give jquery's fadein a target opacity?

Comment: answer edited: sorry, I should have referenced fadeto and not fadein.

Answer (score 2):

please use like :

```
.abc{
opacity: 0.5;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; // first! for ie8
 filter: alpha(opacity=50);     // second! for other ie versions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need to do IE specific things I usually go for the filters built into IE6 and 7. Take care to only feed this to IE though. Apply a little elbow grease and you can make a custom animation with jQuery too I think.

```
*object*.style.filter='progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=*value*,opacity=*value*)';
```

[MSDN: Opacity attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532910%28VS.85%29.aspx)