# Internet Explorer 7 8 : jQuery UI effects work only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

## Context

I use jQuery UI effects (`slide` and `drop`) to open and close a slide.

The following code works on Chrome, Firefox and IE 9.

On IE 7 and 8, I can open and close the slide only once. After the slide stays hidden.

Any idea to resolve that?

- jQuery : `1.8.0`/`1.8.1`
- jQuery UI : `1.8.23`

## Code + [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5aTc/2)

```
// Opens a slide
$('a[data-toggle="slide"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    currentSlide = $(this).attr('href');

    $(currentSlide).show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, _config.effectDuration);
    $('div.modal-backdrop').fadeIn(_config.effectDuration);
});

// Closes the current slide
$('div.modal-backdrop, button.close').click(function () {
    $(currentSlide).hide('drop', { direction: 'right' }, _config.effectDuration);
    $('div.modal-backdrop').fadeOut(_config.effectDuration);
});
```

Comment: new versions of jquery droped support of IE 7

Comment: can you recreate this in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Ibu : our customers use IE 7. I use jQuery 1.8.0 and jQuery UI 1.8.23, are they compatible?

Comment: According to their blog, no they haven't dropped support for IE 7/8 or even 6 for that matter. http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/

Comment: @Shmiddty - I added the jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inline style of the slider (on the second time it shows) is the following in IE8 (compatible mode from IE9):

```
zoom: 1; filter:  alpha(opacity=0); display: block;
```

Which means that it's the filter that sets the opacity to 0 that is the culprit.

Comment: So weird. I will try to change the filter value when opening the slide.

Comment: As seen in this answer to a related question, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1333389/600101, it should use `-ms-filter` for IE8, not `filter`. Might be fixed in jQuery 1.8.1 released the 30th of august.

Comment: And just quickly checking the jQuery UI code the bug must come from jQuery and not the UI extension.

Comment: Did you try to update jQuery to 1.8.1? I saw in the changelog that some issues with IE had been handled. I don't know if they're related but could be worth a shot.

Comment: Yes I updated my source but no changes. I just added a .css(//filter) after the slide effect.

Comment: It's like you said: weird. Anyhow; glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Henrik Ammer, the solution:

```
$(currentSlide)
    .show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, _config.effectDuration)
    .css({ '-ms-filter':'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)', 'filter':'alpha(opacity=100)'});
```