# IE8 opacity animation not working on <sup> tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a <h2>iPhone<sup>®</sup></h2> in my HTML.
Using jQuery to animate the opacity on that element works on everything but the <sup>®</sup> isn't getting animated.

How can I go around that? That is only happening on IE8.

Tried using this but no luck

```
h2 * {
   filter:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted several times before here on SO, IE8 handles opacity differently then IE<8 and IE9. See this answer for instance, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3003079/600101 which handles opacity in IE8.

Comment: Hey Henrik, the issue I'm experiencing is specifically for <sup> tag only. Every other things animates properly. I'm using jQuery remember? It handles browser compatibility.

Comment: If you see this question, http://stackoverflow.com/q/12271112/600101,  that I was involved in yesterday jQuery did use `filter` in IE8. Also, as seen in this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/5586709/600101, (same question as above) if you use `filter` in `IE8` it needs to use `display: block;`.